# I am sudo but cannot edit file or save it

Tags: nvidia, permissions, bumblebee

I became a Ubuntu user 3 months ago, and have been trying to utilize my Nvidia GeForce graphics card approx.10 hours per week.
I am attempting to try this offering;

```
:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable && sudo apt-get -y update <ENTER>            
:~$ sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia <ENTER>
:~$ gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf <ENTER>
```

Edit line 22 to ´Driver=nvidia´ Edit line 47 to ´kernelDriver=nvidia´ Save and run

```
:~$ sudo bumblebee restart <ENTER> then
:~$ optirun glxgears <ENTER>
```

After seeming success at editing, when I try to save and exit I get an **Unable to access file** or **Unable to obtain permission to read file**

How do I get permission to change lines in a just installed file so I can finally use my nvidia GE card? I finally found a good sounding repair but cannot even open it.

Comment: Sorry, but you are rambling ;-) Could you please add in what command you used and the error it generated?

Comment: Just to echo that it's impossible to answer your question at the moment because it's impossible to understand the exact problem from your description. Please edit the question to include some specifics (which files, for instance?). Put yourself in the shoes of somebody reading it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
```

You claim you are sudo here? I claim you are not... you need to do...

```
sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
```

Comment: Thank you for the ideal formatting. I was using root terminal

Comment: Thank you for the ideal formatting. I was using a root terminal and thought that since I was labelled root@mybuntu that made me sudo. Most of my learning has been by tripping over my own code. How **can** I get the nvidia board working? Bumblebee needs to be started so that is my next puzzle, where is it and how to ¨start¨ it.